# Plot legend random Forest r

Tags: r, plot, random-forest

I run the `randomForest` algorithm in `R` and want to plot the `OOB Error` with a legend describing it. However, I cannot seem to get it right.

That is the way it looks:

[image: messed up plot]

Thats the code I used:

```
plot(rfOutput, log = "y", type = "l")
legend("top", colnames(rfOutput$err.rate),col=1:6,cex=0.8,fill=1:6)
```

How would I specify the colors used for the lines as well as the linetype? I dont want it dashed. Furthermore, how would I add the matching legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution where you extract the plot data from `plot(rfOutput...)` and re-plot it using the `ggplot` package:

```
library(randomForest)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# Use random forest example from randomForest package
data(iris)
set.seed(71)
rfOutput <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE, ntree = 6, proximity=TRUE)

# Get OOB data from plot and coerce to data.table
oobData = as.data.table(plot(rfOutput))

# Define trees as 1:ntree
oobData[, trees := .I]

# Cast to long format
oobData2 = melt(oobData, id.vars = "trees")
setnames(oobData2, "value", "error")

# Plot using ggplot
ggplot(data = oobData2, aes(x = trees, y = error, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

The output is as follows:

[image]